# How to set the values of PreferenceActivity(R.xml.preferences) dynamically loading it from SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferenceactivity

I have a MyPreferenceActivity that extends PreferenceActivity like this :

```
public class MyPreferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity{


  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {     
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);  
  }

}
```

I also have custom shared preferences that R.xml.preferences are tied to by individual preference classes...for e.g.

preferences.xml has

```
            <!--EditTextPreference-->
            <com.myapp.preferences.PrimaryNumberPreference
                android:key="PREFS_PRIMARY_NUMBER"
                android:title="@string/primary_number_preference_title" 
                android:summary="@string/primary_number_preference_summary"
                android:dialogTitle="@string/primary_number_preference_dialog_title" 
                    android:dialogMessage="@string/primary_number_preference_dialog_message"  
            />
```

PrimaryNumberPreference.java :

```
public class PrimaryNumberPreference extends EditTextPreference {

Context ctx = null;

public PrimaryNumberPreference(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.ctx = context;
}

public PrimaryNumberPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.ctx = context;
}

public PrimaryNumberPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.ctx = context;

}

@Override
protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
    super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);
    if (positiveResult){    
        customPreferenceibrary.setPrefsPrimaryNumber(getText());
    }
}

}
```

OK so all seems to be in place. Now what I want is everytime the PreferenceActivity is loaded, it should fetch the current sharedpreference values that are stored in their respective key and prepopulate the elements of the PreferenceActivity...

Eg: PrimaryNumber shared preference is set to 1234 when my app is installed. Now if I go to MyPreferenceActivity and browse the PrimaryNumber EditTextPreference, the text box should be prepopulated by 1234.

Something(pseudo code) like :

MyPreferenceActivity.PrimaryNumberPreference.Val = getSharedPreferences(prefsPrimaryNumber)

How can I do that?

**EDIT**

Please let me know if the question is unclear and needs better explanantion. I am sure the answer is a simple implementation of something very standard in android. All PreferenceActivity elements pick the current value to be displayed from the stored SharedPreferences only, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer with the help of suggestions provided by @Mel and Its very easy.

In the class that extends the corresponding PreferenceActivity element(e.g. shown below) just add this.setValue in the constructor of that preference element class. Thats it!

```
public class selectColorPreference extends ListPreference{

    Context ctx = null;
    private String error = null;
    private int prefsRemoteSMSAccess;
    MyPreferencesLibrary myPreferencesLibrary;

    public selectColorPreference(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.ctx = context;

        myPreferencesLibrary = new MyPreferencesLibrary(ctx);
        this.setValue(myPreferencesLibrary.getSharedPreferenceValueForColor());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I see two potential problems:

***Problem One***

If you have a custom preference such as the PrimaryNumberPreference.java you need to manually save the preference when the dialog closes.  Is that what you are doing in **customPreferenceibrary.setPrefsPrimaryNumber(getText());** ??

If they are not committed in this function then I think they need to be. (Or committed somewhere else in onDialogClosed)

***Problem Two***

***Assuming you are commiting the preferences*** in setPrefsPrimaryNumber, I think the setPrefsPrimaryNumber needs to receive two paramenters,

1. The preference name
2. The actual value

I dont think it is enough just to have the key name set in XML (android:key="PREFS_PRIMARY_NUMBER is not enough)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yup, I am saving the preference by overriding onDialogClosed() for all the preferences. Is there a better alternative. I chose this way because i wanted to keep the code modular as its a huge project with loads of library classes using the custom shared preferences. Thnx for your help!

Comment: I don't know about design pros and cons but as long as you are committing the preference it should work.  I think your problem must be the second one (Problem two in my answer).  How does the setPrefsPrimaryNumber know what preferrences to commit if it only has one parameter?

Comment: Thats not a problem at all. Each SetPrefs correspond to a particular sharedprference...setPrefsPrimaryNumber updates Primary_Number_Preference. Same goes for setPrefsSecondaryNumber and so on..these all are public methods in a preference library class! Well, the main problem is how to show the currrent shared preference value in the PreferenceActivity...for eg : Lets say prim numbr is 1234 shored in shared preference. Now when I open the PreferenceActivity and click on Primary Number, the EditText should be pre populated with "1234". How to do that? Got it?

Comment: Assuming that the preferences are saved try this...In your  PrimaryNumberPreference constructor functions add "keyName = this.getKey()"  Then in your preference activity add " pref = (PrimaryNumberPreference) getPreferenceManager().findPreference("PREFS_PRIMARY_NUMBER");
  pref.setText("1234");"

Comment: (Where the "1234" in the comment above is used as a placeholder from a value obtained from SharedPreferences)